# How safe is Asymmetric Encryption

Tags: encryption-asymmetric

How secure is asymmetric encryption when sender encrypts with private key and reciever decrypts with public key but public key has visibility? any one can decrypt it

Answer (score 2):

It's the other way around.. Sender encrypts with public key, and receiver decrypts with its private key..

What you are saying applies to signature.. sender signs with private key, receiver validates signature with public key

Comment: thanks for your comment but I read in the article that sender encrypts with private key and reciever decrypts with public key .but I guess this process is vulnerable

Comment: Well, to be fair, "signing" with a private key is actually encrypting the message or a digest (hash/checksum) thereof, and the receiver validates by decrypting using the public key. And depending on the algorithm, private and public key may sometimes be used for both directions.